# How to calibrate MMC5603 magnetometer

Tags: magnetometer, calibration

I just got a MMC5603 magnetometer from Adafruit however the measurements are unreliable. For example when I convert it to a heading it goes from 200° to 180° and then back to 200° if I move it radially.

Answer (score 1):

To calibrate a magnetometer you should perform hard-iron and soft-iron calibration. There's some guides online about how to do this but I found [this digikey guide](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/how-to-calibrate-a-magnetometer/50f6bc8f36454a03b664dca30cf33a8b) to be the most informative. Adafruit also has a guide [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-sensorlab-magnetometer-calibration/magnetic-calibration-with-motioncal)

I had some issues getting this to work however so here's some tricks

### Using an M1 macbook

Both guides recommend to use MotionCal but it hasn't been updated in several years. If you downloaded the macOS version it might not show any available ports. To fix this you need to compile it from source – you can find details in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/MotionCal/issues/11) but the TL;DR is:

1. `git clone git@github.com:PaulStoffregen/MotionCal.git`
2. `brew install wxwidgets`
3. Open the `Makefile`
4. Comment the line `OS = LINUX`
5. Uncomment the line`OS = MACOSX_CLANG`
6. Under `else ifeq ($(OS), MACOSX)` add `-arch arm64` to the `CFLAGS`
7. Run `make` and it should build

I had some issues with it not building after this which was resolved by deleting the directory and then redoing these steps

### Using an Arduino UNO

Both guides say to use **Adafruit Sensor Lab** which is too large to fit onto an Arduino UNO's flash. Instead you can you use this code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <Adafruit_MMC56x3.h>

/* Assign a unique ID to this sensor at the same time */
Adafruit_MMC5603 mmc = Adafruit_MMC5603(12345);

int loopcount = 0;

// Hard-iron calibration settings
const float hard_iron[3] = {
    0, 0, 0
};

// Soft-iron calibration settings
const float soft_iron[3][3] = {
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1 }
};

void setup(void)
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial)
        delay(10); // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens

    Serial.println("Adafruit_MMC5603 Magnetometer Test");
    Serial.println("");

    /* Initialise the sensor */
    if (!mmc.begin(MMC56X3_DEFAULT_ADDRESS, &Wire)) { // I2C mode
        /* There was a problem detecting the MMC5603 ... check your connections */
        Serial.println("Ooops, no MMC5603 detected ... Check your wiring!");
        while (1)
            delay(10);
    }

    /* Display some basic information on this sensor */
    mmc.printSensorDetails();
}

void loop(void)
{
    static float hi_cal[3];
    // Get a new sensor event
    sensors_event_t event;
    mmc.getEvent(&event);

    // Put raw magnetometer readings into an array
    float mag_data[] = { event.magnetic.x,
        event.magnetic.y,
        event.magnetic.z };

    // Apply hard-iron offsets
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        hi_cal[i] = mag_data[i] - hard_iron[i];
    }

    // Apply soft-iron scaling
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        mag_data[i] = (soft_iron[i][0] * hi_cal[0]) + (soft_iron[i][1] * hi_cal[1]) + (soft_iron[i][2] * hi_cal[2]);
    }

    // 'Raw' values to match expectation of MOtionCal
    Serial.print("Raw:");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(int(mag_data[0] * 10));
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(int(mag_data[1] * 10));
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(int(mag_data[2] * 10));
    Serial.println("");

    // unified data
    Serial.print("Uni:");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(0);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(mag_data[0]);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(mag_data[1]);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(mag_data[2]);
    Serial.println("");

    delay(10);
}
```

which will output the magnetometer data correctly formatted at the correct baud rate. Then you just open up MotionCal, select the right port